# How can a Rails 5 app auto-generate HAML for layouts and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-5

The solution that worked so well for Rails 4, the haml-rails gem, is apparently no longer active (last commit a year ago), and apparently has dependencies that stop it from working with released versions of Rails 5.

Is there any solution for a Rails 5 app that will automatically use Haml for layouts and scaffolded views?

Comment: hm, recently I've used `haml-rails` with `rails 5.0.1` and all worked fine. when I created controller with few actions, its views were generated with `haml` extension

Comment: good to know! the reported issue related to dependencies and Rails 5 is https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/issues/112 and some issues are open after a year with no response so I'm hoping there is a maintained solution for Rails 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like despite the last release being mid-2015, the haml-rails gem is still the way to go, as Igor mentioned in a comment. If someone finds a better (supported) alternative in Rails 5, LMK and I'll select that answer instead of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify haml as a default template engine? In config/application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application

    config.generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :haml
    end
end
```

'haml' gem should be present in your Gemfile

Comment: does not work in rails 5, gives `haml [not found]` when run the scaffolding.

Comment: did you include gem 'haml' in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes, globally eg not inside any group. Must use have haml-rails AFAIK, the generator template_engine statement doesn't work to default to use haml for views.